# the smallest value for a constant in an inequality

Tags: real-analysis

What is the smallest value for the constant $\alpha$ in the inequality:
$$xy^2  \le 3x^3+\alpha  y^3$$

I've tried but without results
can someone  give me a hint?

Comment: Try factoring out a $y^2$ of two terms. I'm not sure what you mean by "smallest constant" as there are solutions to this inequality no matter the value of alpha

Comment: For each fixed positive $x$, the inequality holds for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$ only if $\alpha>x$. So, if there is no restriction on the range of $x$ and $y$, there is no $\alpha$ such that the inequality is true for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, letting along the smallest one.

Comment: As you don't say the range of values for $(x,y)$, your issue has no solutions. Give this range. Besides, check the text of your problem ...

Comment: I beg your pardon but I made a mistake...i changed the text!

Comment: You still need to answer the questions! Are you talking about _all_  $x$ and $y$, or just some? No matter what $\alpha$ is, the inequality is false  for $x=-1$, $y=0$. (Probably all you need to do is add the words in the original statement of the problem that you left out in your post.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, for a fixed $u$, we want the $c$ such that
$xy^2  \le ux^3+c  y^3
$
holds for all $x, y > 0$.

Dividing by $y^3$
and letting $x/y = r$,
this is
$r \le ur^3+c$
or
$c \ge r-ur^3$.

If $f(r) = r-ur^3$,
then 
$f'(r)
=1-3ur^2$
so $f'(r)  = 0$
at
$r_u = \dfrac1{\sqrt{3u}}
$
where
$f(r_u)
=r_u(1-ur_u^2)
=\dfrac1{\sqrt{3u}}(1-u\dfrac1{3u})
=\dfrac{2}{3\sqrt{3u}}
$.

Since $f''(r)
=-6ur
\lt 0$
if
$r > 0$,
this is a maximum.

Your case is $u=3$,
for which
$r_u = \dfrac1{3}
$
and
$f(r_u)
=\dfrac{2}{9}
 $.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume $x,y$ are positive numbers.

Notice $3x^3 + \alpha y^3 = 3x^3 + \frac{\alpha}{2}y^3 + \frac{\alpha}{2}y^3$. By AM $\ge$ GM, we get
$$3x^3 + \alpha y^3 \ge 3 \sqrt[3]{\frac34\alpha^2}xy^2 = \left(\frac{9\alpha}{2}\right)^{2/3}xy^2$$
This implies when $\alpha \ge \frac29$, we will have

$$3x^3 + \alpha y^3 \ge xy^2$$

When $\alpha = \frac29$, above inequality becomes an equality at $x : y = 1 : 3$. This implies $\frac29$ is the smallest $\alpha$ you can have.